# Perfect placement of a shape to delimit a corner

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corners

Is there a way to perfectly make those corners? I am kind of eyeballing the position of the circle, but wondering if there is a way to place it perfectly touching both lines it is supposed to touch on a single vertex each.

[image: example]

Comment: What version of illustrator? New versions have a handle to do rounds. Anyway if not then read this duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65706/illustrator-problem-line-quarter-circle-rounded-corners-deformation/65720#65720

Comment: Illustrator CC, thank you for the reply, although I showed a circle in my example, the shape I want to snap to two other is not always a circle.

Comment: Well that is a different can of worms, there is not even a guarntee that the shape may in fact fit. But you could use gradiebt descent methods.

Comment: There's a plugin which makes this supereasy: https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/  The rounding tool is called Dynamic Corners. They have a free 14-day trial version available. It can also do negative rounding and chamfers.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't corner rounding tool, you can use the following workaround. It's useful only, if you do not need exact circular rounding with known radius:

[image]

1. add new anchor points into the red circles and remove the anchor point in the green circle. Use those anchor manipulation tools which are placed under the pen in the toolbox.
2. Inserted anchor point A was sharp because the path was perfectly straight. Now theres a new corner
3. Fix the sharp corner A by dragging with the anchor type conversion tool. A handle appears and you can drag it for a good fillet curvature.

In theory it's possible that editing tne anchor point in the green circle gives the wanted result. For it other anchor points must exist near enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Smart Guides and see if "snapped"? You should be able to see, by zooming in, if the paths are perfectly in sync.

Comment: I zoomed and used outline view, but it only snaps to one vertex or line (or any other smart guide).

Comment: Isn't there a way, using the X-Y coordinates, to perfectly place it? Can you upload the file somewhere for me to try?

Comment: Even with the coordinates I will be eyeballing the shape position. That object is just an example, I wanted a technique to apply to my work since this kind of problem is recurrent.